# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -vto see invocation)

Tags: ios, swift, apple-m1

This question already asked but i didn't get any solution , i have a Intel based macbook pro when i run this project its worked perfectly but when same project i run on M1 chip mac mini then show this error . i try to many way to solve this but every time i failed , if any one have this solution please drop your comment Advance Thanks[image]

Comment: Just use real device to solved this problem. main reason of this project for different architecture of M1 and Int chipset.